# route parameter symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I defined this route

```
teln_operator_edit_1:
    pattern:  /edit1/{id}/{step}
    defaults: { _controller: TelnOperatorBundle:Operator:step1 }
```

and I get

/Symfony/web/app_dev.php/edit1/13/1
I want to get the step value 
how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You'll get URL parameter value into your action method as a parameter:

```
public function step1Action($id, $step) {
    // ...
}
```

Make sure method parameter names are equivalent to parameter names in your pattern.

Comment: this what I tried but when I asked echo($step) it gives 112. I can not understand why

Comment: how does your request URL look like?

Comment: I found out the error I had a previous echo. thank u very mauch @usoban